# Why Does a Function Extends Holomorphically when The Related Sum Converges?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, complex-analysis, convergence-divergence, continuity

I have seen some cases where  to prove a function is holomorphic, it is proven that a sum derived from that function is convergent.

For example, in [Newman's Short Proof of the Prime Number Theorem by  D. Zagier](https://people.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/zagier/files/doi/10.2307/2975232/fulltext.pdf), I found two examples,  **The first one is**-

[image]

***So, $\zeta(s)-\frac{1}{s-1}$ extends holomorphically to $Re(s)>0$ when a series derived from it converges absolutely.***

**The second example is -**

[image]

***In above example, $\Phi(s)$ extends meromorphically  because "the final sum" converges.***

**Question:**

Why does a function extends holomorphically/meromorphically to $Re(s)>0$ when the related sum converges? What is the intuitive explanation? Is there any proof?

Also, explain what does it means when a function "extends holomorphically/meromorphically to $Re(s)>0$"  under the context of the topic.

If possible please attach related elementary lecture/book/online documents for better understanding.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like there are two steps here: that certain sums of holomorphic functions remain holomorphic and that certain functions deserve to be called "extensions" of others.

The first part can be captured as follows

> Let $f_1,f_2,f_3,\ldots$ be a sequence of holomorphic functions which converge to some function $f_{\infty}$ and so that this convergence is uniform on compact sets. Then $f_{\infty}$ is holomorphic.

This can be proven by using [Morera's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morera%27s_theorem) (which is the converse of Cauchy's integral theorem) and the fact that we can use uniform convergence to equate
$$\oint_{\gamma}f_{\infty}(z)\,dz = \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\oint_{\gamma}f_n(z)\,dz$$
where we know that every term on the right is $0$ because of Cauchy's integral theorem, which implies that the term on the left is zero, which implies holomorphicity of $f_{\infty}$. (Aside: I've written this argument out assuming the domain in question is simply connected, but holomorphic is a local condition and open sets are locally simply connected, so no generality is lost here)

This has a consequence:

> Let $g_1,g_2,g_3,\ldots$ be a sequence of holomorphic functions such that, for any compact set $C$ the sum $\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\max_{z\in C}|g_i(z)|$ converges. Then $\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}g_i(z)$ is holomorphic.

This follows by considering applying the prior theorem to the set of partial sums. This is the principal fact using to establish that some functions are holomorphic in the text you included.

Aside from this fact, everything else follows by noting that sums and differences of holomorphic functions are holomorphic.

For the second part, the word "extension" just means that if you have a holomorphic function $F$ on a domain $U_1$ and a holomorphic function $G$ on a larger domain $U_2$, we call $G$ an extension if $G|_{U_1} = F$ - that is, if $G$ agrees with $F$ everywhere where $F$ is defined. The author doesn't explicitly check this condition, but shows that these various sums converge on a desirably large set and calls them "extensions" because they agree with some previous definition on a smaller set.

Answer (score 0):

The precise reasoning they mean is thisone :

- $$F(s) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{-s}-\int_n^{n+1} x^{-s}dx$$
  converges absolutely and locally uniformly for  $\Re(s) > 0$, thus

  (Cauchy integral formula + that $ \sum_{n=1}^N n^{-s}-\int_n^{n+1} x^{-s}dx$ is analytic)

  $F(s)$ is analytic for $ \Re(s) > 0$.
- For $\Re(s) > 1$ $$\zeta(s)-\frac1{s-1}= F(s)$$

That's it, we have continued $\zeta(s)-\frac1{s-1}$ analytically to $\Re(s) > 0$ and $\zeta(s)$ meromorphically.

Answer (score 0):

This is the identity theorem for analytic functions in a slight abuse of notation.

The setting is that a given (usually by a formula like a Dirichlet series or integral but could be something else too) analytic $F(s)$ is defined on a domain $D$.

By some manipulations, we show that there is an analytic $G(s)$ defined on a larger domain $U$ containing $D$ s.t. $G(s)=F(s)$ on $D$.

We then conclude that the original $F$ extends (with the value $F(s)=G(s)$) on the larger $U$.

Note that in general **this does not imply that the original formula for $F$ extends** too!!

Sometimes we may even get $G(s)$ only on some $U$ that has nonempty (hence open) intersection with $D$ but doesn't contain it; then we still can and do conclude that $F$ extends to $D \cup U$